# Angular component with dynamic input properties for list

Tags: angular, angular2-components

Just wondering if this is at all possible

The scenario is:
I want to create a list component using `*ngFor`, but i want the `*ngFor` embedded in the component itself

**foo-list-items.html** (component)

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of list" (click)="goto(item)">
       {{ item.name }}<br />
       <small> Email: {{ item.email }} </small>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Would it be possible with `@Input() name:any` to make the looped name property based on a input from the component parent?

So in the html one could write

**Parent html**

```
<foo-list-items [list]="usersList" 
                (onItemClicked)="gotoUser($event)" 
                [name]="item.name">
</foo-list-items>
```

Where `[name]="item.name"` is the dynamic property passed into the child component, with which to reference in the loop.

So for instance if one has 2 lists

1. User List
2. Program List

However the data for the `name` property is `.name` for the User List and `.programName` for the Program List. Can you define the property for item in the `*ngFor`loop as an input value on the parent component?

So basically creating a generic `*ngFor` no matter what the `item.name` is. The name in the loop, of the child component, will display for `item.name` or `item.programName`

Comment: Pass in the name of the property you want to display. I don't see the problem.

Comment: How would you reference it in the loop though? because in the the loop  `*ngFor="let item of list"` then one needs to reference `item` in the loop based on the properties in `list` ... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a string as an input property to the `foo-list-items` component such as:

```
<foo-list-items [list]="usersList" 
            (onItemClicked)="gotoUser($event)" 
            [name]="'name'">
</foo-list-items>
```

or

```
<foo-list-items [list]="programList" 
            (onItemClicked)="gotoUser($event)" 
            [name]="'programName'">
</foo-list-items>
```

and then in the component template use array key (`object['property']`) rather than dot notation:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list" (click)="goto(item)">
   {{ item[name] }}<br />
   <small> Email: {{ item.email }} </small>
  </li>
</ul>
```